# Oracle-Join with same table multiple times with different where condition

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Here is my case,

[image]

```
SELECT 
A.TAB1_COL1,B.TAB2_COL4,C.TAB2_COL4 
FROM TABLE1 A, 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM 
        (SELECT TAB2_COL1, TAB2_COL2, TAB2_COL4, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TAB2_COL1,TAB2_COL2 ORDER BY TAB2_COL3 DESC ) AS ROW_NUM 
            FROM TABLE2 
            WHERE TAB2_COL2=2
        ) WHERE ROW_NUM=1
    ) B ON A.TAB1_COL1=B.TAB2_COL1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM 
        (SELECT TAB2_COL1, TAB2_COL2, TAB2_COL4, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TAB2_COL1,TAB2_COL2 ORDER BY TAB2_COL3 DESC ) AS ROW_NUM 
            FROM TABLE2 WHERE TAB2_COL2=5
        ) WHERE ROW_NUM=1
    ) C ON A.TAB1_COL1=C.TAB2_COL1 AND A.TAB1_COL2=C.TAB2.COL5 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM 
        (SELECT TAB2_COL1, TAB2_COL2, TAB2_COL4, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TAB2_COL1,TAB2_COL2 ORDER BY TAB2_COL3 DESC ) AS ROW_NUM 
            FROM TABLE2 WHERE TAB2_COL2=8
        ) WHERE ROW_NUM=1
    ) D ON A.TAB1_COL1=D.TAB2_COL1
```

This code will work.But, I'm left joining with same table multiple times. In my case, it was around 25 times. Reference table has around 200 million records. Partition to remove dups is taking much time.

Any other effective way of writing to make it process faster. Kindly help.

Thanks

Comment: You've left out the initial select line from the query. What is it that you're selecting to get the value columns?

Comment: Updated.Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select t1.tab1_col1,
       max(case when tab2_col2 = 2 then tab2_col4 end),
       max(case when tab2_col2 = 5 then tab2_col4 end),
       max(case when tab2_col2 = 8 then tab2_col4 end)
from table1 t1 left join
     (select t2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by tab2_col1, tab2_col2 order by tab2_col3 desc) as seqnum
      from table2 t2
     ) t2
     on t1.tab1_col1 = t2.tab2_col1
group by t1.tab1_col1;
```